# Can not submit form with different action (url)

Tags: laravel, forms, routes, action

I go to link `domain.com/detail/01`

In this page I have a form with action is `domain.com/view-info/profile/1` and method is `POST`. But when I submit form it show `Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.`
Note: 2 url different `namespace` and `middleware`.

Route : `Route::post('view-info/{$id}', 'EmployersController@viewProfile')->name('view-profile');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `$` from route parameter:

```
Route::post('view-info/{id}', 'EmployersController@viewProfile')->name('view-profile');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I see. this is my mistake :thumbsub